# How to print the results of CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have tried to train the CNN model with about 700 images and 35 classes with the lines of code below, don't know where I am wrong and how when I finish training I can print and check the results. I have consulted the ways but there are only 2 classes and use the if-else form, so I don't know how it will work with many classes

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu',input_shape = (200,200,3)),
          tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
          #
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
          #
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
          #
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
          #
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
          ##
          tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
          ##
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', name ='layer1'),
          ##
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
          ])

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model_fit= model.fit(train_dataset, 
                     steps_per_epoch = 16,
                     epochs = 100,
                     )
```

Comment: `sigmoid` with one neuron is binary classification, so two classes. You have 35 classes. You need to use `softmax` with 35 neurons.

Comment: I have trained but how can I print the results?

Comment: @NguyễnKhang what do you mean by results? If you mean the accuracy of the train data on your model, it is sent to output after each epoch. However you should also consider using a validation set that, after each epoch, shows the accuracies on unseen data (it can be passed as input to the `fit` method). You can also `model.evaluate(...)` other data to show the accuracies on test data after training.

Comment: I mean, how do I make it recognize the corresponding label name?

Comment: @NguyễnKhang if I understand correctly you are asking how to make a prediction. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-class classification you should use a `softmax` activation function. The softmax function normalizes a set of N real numbers into a probability distribution such that they sum up to 1. For K = 2, the softmax and sigmoid function are the same.

So the problem is that you are using a `sigmoid` activation function instead of a `softmax`. What is happening is that even if you think you are training 35 different classes, since you set a binary loss and sigmoid activation, the network is trained to recognize 34 of your classes as one label, and the remaining class as the other label, which is clearly not what you want.

I suggest you to replace the last piece of code that you have with something like this:

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
          loss=loss_fn,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And to use `activation = 'softmax'` instead of `'sigmoid'` on your last Dense layer.

Then, to make a prediction (to make the model infer the class of your test samples) you simply do:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: I think you confuse multi-label classification with multi-class classification.

Comment: Ops sorry my bad @Frightera